# Orlicz spaces and $\phi$-functions

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, levy-processes

A $\phi$-function $f$ is usually defined as a continuous function $f=\mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+$ such that:

(1) $f$ is nondecreasing.

(2) $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.

(3) $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=+\infty$.

Then it is possible to define a continuous modular $\rho$ on the space of measurable real valued functions on some measured space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ via the formula:
$$\rho(x)=\int_\Omega f(|x(t)|) \mu(dt)$$
The associated modular space is called an Orlicz space.

These spaces are useful to characterize the space of functions integrable with respect to a Lévy process. However, in "Spectral Representations of Infinitely Divisible Processes" (PTRF, 1989) by B. Rajput and J. Rosinski, the function $\Phi_0$ does not always coincides with the usual definition of a $\phi$-function, and in the case of a symmetric compound Poisson process with jumps $\pm 1$, $\Phi_0$ is bounded and does not satisfy (3).

What is the difference? Is there a reference where (3) is not always assumed?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I can't give an answer, but I remember that there are some converse results, saying something like "such and such condition on $f$ is necessary for the resulting space to be linear/... Probably you find such a result in Rao/Ren's "Theory of Orlicz spaces" or Bennet and Sharpley's "Interpolation of operators".

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did not find anything in Rao/Ren, but I did not know the other reference, I will have a look!.

Comment: You are dealing with Musielak-Orlicz space, so Rao and Ren will be of no use. Best go to Musielak (1983) (reference [16] in your article) and see what conditions he assumes. Usual condition is convexity which gives you (3) automatically. Having said this, I have seen papers with non-convex modulars. Nowak (1989) has some statements about those.